# Fiddling with simple lightbox effect. Images won't go away

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox, photo

So, I'm messing with a photo gallery lightbox effect.  It's very simple and jerry-rigged but for some reason the other images won't disappear when I click on the one I want to enlarge even though the function I made should set everything that isn't the clicked on image hidden.  It works the first time but every subsequent time, no matter which of the two images I click on, the other remains there.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Lightbox Effect</title>          
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
            <script src="Java.js"></script>
        </head>
            <body>
            <div class="lightbox">
                <main>
                <div class="X" onclick="goBack()"><a href="#">X</a></div>           
                <img class="woods1" onclick="bigPic1()" src="Images/Woods1.jpg">
                <img class="woods2" onclick="bigPic2()" src="Images/Woods2.jpg">
                <img src="Images/Woods5.jpg">
                <img src="Images/Woods6.jpg">
            </div>          
        </main> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
main div{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid white;
    position:fixed;
    right:1px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
main a{
    text-decoration:none !important;
    font-size:450%;
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
    left:2px;
    color:white;
}
main img{
    margin:20px 0px 0px 50px;
    max-width:20%;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var pics=document.getElementsByClassName('woods1')
var light=document.getElementsByClassName('lightbox')
var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')
var close=document.getElementsByClassName('X')
var pics2=document.getElementsByClassName('woods2')

function bigPic1(){
    light[0].style.visibility="hidden";
    body[0].style.background="black";
    pics[0].style.visibility="visible";
    close[0].style.visibility="visible";
    pics[0].style.transform="scale(2.5)";   
}
function bigPic2(){
    light[0].style.visibility="hidden";
    body[0].style.background="black";
    pics2[0].style.visibility="visible";
    close[0].style.visibility="visible";
    pics2[0].style.transform="scale(2.5)";  
}
function goBack(){
    light[0].style.visibility="visible";
    body[0].style.background="none";
    close[0].style.visibility="hidden";
    pics[0].style.transform="scale(1)"; 
    pics2[0].style.transform="scale(1)";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps at this point you could provide a plain-language description of what you *want* to happen? In following your code however, not seeing the logic of setting the `light` to hidden in `bigPic1` and `bigPic2` but only setting it to visible in `goBack`.

Comment: Ah.  Well, I put everything in a lightbox div so what I'm trying to do is make everything that isn't the pic I'm clicking on hidden and change the background to black at the same time.  Like I said, this is a real bare bones code.  I'm really trying to figure out why the other image isn't staying hidden.  The other images go into hidden mode just fine, it's just the ones with the functions attached to them that seems to stay on the screen for some reason.  It's fine for the first time you click on them and only becomes an issue when clicking on them back and forth.